# Rails: how to tell if Spring is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-spring

In recent versions of Rails they've set `config.cache_classes = true` in `config/environments/test.rb`. This makes sense to me, as we won't typically be dynamically reloading classes. However, when we run with Spring, it complains that this should be set to `false`. I would love it if there was a way to thread the needle and accommodate both, something like:

```rb
config.cache_classes = !Spring.enabled?
```

I'm not seeing a way to accomplish this, though. Is there some way to tell if spring is active when the application is booting?

Comment: If your app is loading Spring before your test suite runs (check bin/rspec and/or bin/rails) then it'll always be loaded. However if you start it manually you could use `defined?(Spring)`.

Comment: For me it looks like it's defined regardless of whether it's using Spring or not. I put a `binding.pry` inside my `test.rb` and with or without running with `spring rspec ...` it had `Spring` defined.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```rb
require 'spring/env'
Spring::Env.new.server_running?
=> true
```